# Sandbox permission errors in Chrome console but I'm not using any iframes

Tags: google-chrome, permissions, sandbox

I keep getting these errors even when the html of my page contains no frames:

> Blocked script execution in '[url]' because the document's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-scripts' permission is not set.
>
> Blocked form submission to '[url]' because the form's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-forms' permission is not set.

Googling these errors return results mostly for people who are using frames. Simple form and the submit is not js-driven but a regular html submit button...

I am lost. Anyone out there getting these for non-frame pages?

Comment: Some plugins can use iframes. Especially plugins for sending files.

Comment: I have this same error with a file-field upload. Not sure how to fix it yet.

Comment: I am getting a similar error.  Could it simply be referring to the single "_top" frame used for every page by default?

Comment: btw, the website I was using is a company internal one, but works when the page with the form opens as a new window/pop-up.  The only reason it sometimes opens as a new tab and experiences this problem behavior is when, on my Mac, I have a full screen Chrome window open on my other monitor.  When I click a link, and don't have another Chrome window on my main space on my main monitor, or I have last focused the other window, it opens over there that way.

Comment: This happens to me when I click on a link in a CRM to open a link in a new tab to our site. All form submissions fail, even after navigating to other pages. Only works when I copy the URL and paste in a new tab. Nothing about "sandbox" in any of the headers. Still researching.

Answer (score 0):

It is as if *a plug-in or module* your site uses takes advantage of `CSP`'s `sandbox` directive. One of several relaxations on the directive happens to be `allow-forms`. Please refer to MDN: [Mozilla's Dev Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/sandbox): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/sandbox